# How to prove $\operatorname{val}(f) = f^+(X)-f^-(X)$ in flow networks?

Tags: network-flow

In flow networks, for any subset $X$, the $\operatorname{val}(f) = f^+(X) - f^-(X)$. What is this theorem called and how can I prove it?

I know that $f^-(\mathrm{sink}) - f^+(\mathrm{sink})=\sum\limits_{v \in X} f^+(v)-\sum\limits_{v \in X} f^-(v) $. But then I don't know how to simplify it...

$val(f) = f^-(\mathrm{sink}) - f^+(\mathrm{sink})$

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the definitions of $val(f)$ and $f^\pm(X)$?

Comment: $X$ is a subset of the nodes in the network including the source but not sink. Then $f^-(X)$ is the sum of the in flow of all $x$ in $X$, and $f^+(X)$ is the sum of the out flow of all $x$ in $X$.

Comment: Consider the following three set of edges: 1) edges going out from $X$, 2) edges coming into $X$, 3) edges with both ends on $X$. If you use this in your second formula and cancel out edges from the second set, you should get your first formula.